label key "Fare" not being fetched in the evaluator component of a tfx pipeline
i am using the evaluator component after a trainer component in a tfx pipeline to predict fares from the chicago taxi trips data. in the evaluator component, after the predictions are made, the "fare" label is not being fetched.
# Define signatures for serving
    @tf.function(input_signature=[
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="trip_miles"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name="trip_seconds"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name="trip_start_hour"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name="company_size_encoded"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name="pickup_community_area"),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name="dropoff_community_area"),
    ])
    def serving_step(trip_miles, trip_seconds, trip_start_hour, company_size_encoded,
                     pickup_community_area, dropoff_community_area):
        inputs = [
            trip_miles, trip_seconds, trip_start_hour, 
            company_size_encoded, pickup_community_area, dropoff_community_area
        ]
        predictions = model(inputs, training=False)
        return {"predictions": predictions}
    
    signatures = {
        "serving_default": serving_step.get_concrete_function(),
    }
    
    # Save the model
    tf.keras.models.save_model(
        model, 
        fn_args.serving_model_dir,
        signatures=signatures
    )

this is how i saved my model using the serving_default signature. what should i change so that the "fare" column from the examples gets fetched so i can calculate the r2 score?
